# Access Views and Controllers which are under Sub folders for specific scenarios?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, attributes

On my all actions methods I use this route attribute to use - sign.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("lower-case-converter")]
        public IActionResult Index(BassModel model)
```

Since I have many case converters I want to put them inside a folder called "CaseConverters". I made a folder in views folder called ""CaseConverters". Note that there are other tools too.
So I changed the route attribute like this

```
 [Route("~/CaseConverters/lower-case-converter")]
```

Above not worked. So I changed it to

```
 [Route("/CaseConverters/lower-case-converter")]
```

Still its not working. Note that i want to add this folder to Controllers folder too. How to acehve this?

Answer (score 0):

To specify a route for `lower-case-converter` action inside your `CaseConverters` controller you can specify the route as follows, (I'm assuming `CaseConverters` is your controller. If yes It's better to use the correct naming convention. Ex: `CaseConvertersController`)

```
[Route("CaseConverters/lower-case-converter")]
```

You can also specify a route template for your controller class. as follows,

```
[Route("CaseConverters")]
public class CaseConvertersController : Controller
{
    [Route("lower-case-converter")]
    public IActionResult LowerCaseConverter()
    {
        //you implementation
    }
}
```

For the above code route template for the action is `CaseConverters/lower-case-converter`. And also make sure use have used `app.UseMvc()` and `MapRoute()` methods inside `Configure()` method inside the `startup.cs`